# url parameter to save it in JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, url

I would like to insert a parameter value (**AS A NUMBER**) found the url into my javascript code.. So basically i have the following url www.rene-zamm.com/mp-dthanks.asp?gglid=123123123

Now i have the following javascript code in the same page and i want that number in the url to be visible also in the javascript code where i have written querydata..:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">


function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
try {
var querydata = gup("gglid");
var gwoTracker=_gat._getTracker("UA-1639156-3");
gwoTracker._trackPageview("/" + **querydata** + "/goal");
alert(querydata);
}catch(err){}

</script>
```

For some reason the querydata is showing as text and not as number.. please help

Comment: It will appear like `/123123123/goal`, how do you expect it to appear?

Comment: What do you mean, "as a text and not as number"?

Comment: all i want is when i click on view source of the page, i want to see the number which  is taken from the URL and not querydata... so basically when i click view source i see gwoTracker._trackPageview(/123123123/goal);

Comment: @Rene Zammit: Why are you worried about viewing it so in page's *source code* at all?

Comment: @Rene Zammit, when you look at the source code in the page, it always show's you the way you code it, unless you are parsing it inside a server tag. but the actual value of then when it is passed to `gwoTracker._trackPageview` it should look like what you want it to be.

Comment: @Sarfraz: because thats a google script and to work properly i need to have a numeric value hardcoded in the sourcecode.. the numeric value needs to be taken from the url (this is working) and then placed instead of querydata.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that `querydata` is going to be a number, just use `parseInt(querydata)` and it will return a number, integer to be exact